# ESB backed database

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, mule, cxf

Background:

I work in a organisation, uses hundreds of software systems, we identify which system owns which category of data, then carefully select the data we want to expose to the other systems. then pull them into a single Oracle database.AKA master data.

then each system read the status of the other system through this shared database pattern.

Problem:

access control, data handling, and lack of event notification, logic routing caused us lots of time and effort. We want to add a ESB layer in front of the

Potential Solution:

we are looking at SOA at moment, in specific Enterprise Service Bus Pattern. 
we aware there are options like Camel, Mule and ServceMix. But I wander is there any resource, can assists our implementation?

is there any project been done the same way, e.g ESB fronting a Oracle database access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find much in this strict sense. ESB is basically made for transferring messages between enterprise services. A DB is not an enterprise service. In this case you'd need processing beans that handle your specific need.

What you could do, however, is to put a service in front of your DB. This service could then expose the DB in some format. For example, SOAP over JMS seems fitted to your use case. SOAP can handle security and access, JMS gives you asynchrousness and exactly-once delivery guarantee, which will be needed if working with a DB. ESB frameworks can handle JMS and SOAP very well.

So instead of looking for a "ESB backed database", as you called it, this service may be something that you can look for on the market, and then you can route client services by using an ESB, which makes sense.

Comment: if you look at the following reference, it sounds like what we trying to do, but not specific enough https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/etl-tools-vs-esb

Comment: and I totally understand what you are saying, because thats what we thought originally. but I feel there are other ways to use the ESB

Comment: One thing came to my mind. You might want to look at LinkedIn's Databus. https://github.com/linkedin/databus

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean with your link. I was involved with something similar with Mule back in 2008. Works great, but you have to implement these things by yourself as part of the ESB. Would be great to have this part already done, as I said in my answer.

Comment: spakendralo man, can you explain what did you mean by SOAP over ESB? you mean expose the database as a SOAP service, then put a JMS service in front of the SOAP? and thanks for the databus link.

Comment: I wrote "SOAP over JMS", not "SOAP over ESB". I meant to expose the database as a SOAP service, yes, a SOAP service that uses the JMS protocol (instead of the more commonly used SOAP over HTTP, which does not guarantee transactions and exactly-once processing). Then you could have the ESB to "expose" this service to clients and handle some things like routing or protocol transformation, for instance, if clients cannot do SOAP/JMS. In this way it may be easier to find a product on the market that already does half the job (expose the DB as a SOAP/JMS service or similar).

Comment: Thanks Spakendralo, confusing bit is that the definition of SOAP is XML over HTTP. and I don't know what do you mean by SOAP service using JMS, is there any example I can see please

Comment: It's a common missinterpretation. SOAP is not XML/HTTP (althought it's frequently used in this way), it's just a messaging protocol - it does not include transport specifications. SOAP can operate over any transport protocol like HTTP, SMTP, TCP, UDP, JMS. Most ESBs support SOAP/JMS out of the box. You can Google any of the ESBs (FUSE/Mule/WSO2/MessageBroker...) with "SOAP over JMS".